# Testing incremental development of windows service

Tags: wcf, testing, service

Currently working on a WCF service running as a windows service.

I've made an installer and written a little script which adds a user account for it to run under and then registers and starts the service under than account. And a build step in visual studio to copy it to a discrete folder so we're not running directly off the solution. All works fine.

However, as I extend and improve this service, testing it is becoming a bit of a pain. Each time I want to check my changes I have to stop the service, rebuild, re-start the service and re-attach visual studio to the process before I can step through.

Just wondering if there's a quicker or better method of doing this without writing some proxy host for all the services? Unit tests won't cut it in this instance because the service needs to do system-ish stuff like connecting to Active Directory endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but I recently solved part of this using build events as follows:

Pre-build event:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" neq "Debug" goto NoStop

echo Attempting to stop windows service MyService
net stop MyService > MyService.log
if "%errorlevel%" neq "0" (call )
type MyService.log

:NoStop
```

Post-build event:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" neq "Debug" goto NoStart

findstr "/c:stopped successfully" MyService.log >nul
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" net start MyService
(call )

:NoStart
```

Features of this approach:

- The configuration is checked and if I'm not building in Debug, then the whole bit is skipped.
- The NET STOP command will *try* to stop your service and the if command below it will swallow any errors that might occur.  This is great if your service isn't installed or if it isn't running.
- Since the service is stopped, the service EXE is unlocked and the build doesn't fail with those annoying "file is locked" errors.
- The post-build event will *only* start the service if the pre-build event was successful in shutting it down.  The FINDSTR command searches the log file created during the pre-build event for the string "stopped successfully."  If it is found, the NET START is called.  Either way, errors are swallowed by the (call ) on the next line.

This is working for me in Visual Studio 2015 running on Windows 7.  Hope this helps somebody!